# marker text is not appear on click from kml iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, kml, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a .kml file in which I have some markers. I have added text for each markers which should appear on click as expected behaviour. But the text is not appear when I click on any marker.

I imported GoogleMaps, GoogleUtilities, GoogleMapsUtils in my view controller, and uses GMSMapView to load a google map.

Here is my .kml file code snippet:

```
<Style id="icon-1625-0288D1-labelson-nodesc">
  <IconStyle>
    <color>ffd18802</color>
    <scale>1</scale>
    <Icon>
      <href>https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
  <BalloonStyle>
    <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
  </BalloonStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <name>Registration</name>
  <styleUrl>#icon-1625-0288D1-labelson-nodesc</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>
      -6.2114139,53.3265571,0
    </coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Here is the iOS side of code:

```
let kmlParser = GMUKMLParser(url: kmlFileURL)
kmlParser.parse()

let renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(
    map: map,
    geometries: kmlParser.placemarks,
    styles: kmlParser.styles,
    styleMaps: kmlParser.styleMaps
)

renderer.render()
```